# Data-Driven Unit Test with MSTest : How to read and validate records from CSV file?

Tags: csv, mstest, data-driven

I use the MsTest and Data Driven approach for unit testing.

So far I have a Data.csv file with 5 rows added in my Unit Test project and I want to validate and output the UserId for each corresponding orgId and username.

For example, for Orgid `'80010'` and username `'Malika'` - expected `userid = 0000000047`

[data.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHJvG.png)

How can I set up the data driven test method to read and validate the correct userId from the .CSV file?

`C# Code:`

```
using System;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace AuthenticationServiceTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UT_GetUserIdFromUserName
    {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestMethod]
        [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", @"Data\Data.csv", "Data#csv", 
        DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Arrange
            int ExpUserId = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["0000000047"]);
            int orgId = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow[1]);
            int username = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow[2]);



            // Act
            string UserId = string.Empty;

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(ExpUserId, UserId);
            Console.WriteLine("Expected UserId: " + ExpUserId);
            Console.WriteLine("Actual UserId: " + UserId);

        }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pick a specific ID the unit test engine will take care of parsing the file row by row.
You have to use the the `TestContext.DataRow["column" or index]` to get the value from a specific column of the CSV file.

```
int ExpUserId = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["0000000047"]);
```

Should be either

```
int ExpUserId = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow[0]);
```

or

```
int ExpUserId = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["userId"]);
```